# Android Studio - MainActivity.java can't see id attributes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, listview

I gave an id attribute: 
android: id="@+id/animation_layout"
in the default layout (numbered as 1) in the activity_main.xml

But when I tried to call it in the MainActivity.java by its id:
ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.animation_layout);

- It won't find it  (numbered as 2)

What am I missing?

[image]

also attached the code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/animation_layout"
android:background="@drawable/gradients_list"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

and the Java code:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Gradient animation

    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.animation_layout);
    AnimationDrawable  animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) constraintLayout.getBackground();
    animationDrawable.setEnterFadeDuration(2000);
    animationDrawable.setEnterFadeDuration(4000);
    animationDrawable.start();
```

Thank you for helping :)

Comment: just go on the android build menu and run the clean command! it will solve the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens sometime since new android update! that you even provide ids in xml but still the java api of android does not fetch them! so you need to do this step!

1: clean the build removes the old built cache! and this should solve the problem

[image]

2: if that does not make your id read bale in java you can use the Rebuild option from the same menu!

3: if that does not work either you can go with the FILE-> invalidate cache and restart

Comment: Sometimes it works just by syncing again the gradle, but your solutions is good.

Comment: yeah basically if you sync the gradle it runs the clean command automatically! as you can see in the Project's build.gradle file there is this Clean function defined for it!  @Jsperk

Comment: @EliranLiriElgozi up vote it ! I am glad that it helped!